# SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities | Selenium geckodriver fail

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, archlinux

I tried to run test script with selenium, but got this exception: `org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities`

Full stacktrace:

```
1601395316102   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:15504
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'arch', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.8.12-arch1-1', java.version: '14.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace: 
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:147)
    at Test.main(Test.java:14)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

#### Code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriverLogLevel;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "src/main/resources/geckodriver");
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.setLogLevel(FirefoxDriverLogLevel.TRACE);

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

        driver.get("http://google.com");
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

#### My environment is:

- OS: Arch Linux 5.8.12-arch1-1
- Browser: Firefox Browser version: 81.0 (64-bit)
- Browser Driver version: Geckodriver: 0.27.0
- Language: Java openjdk-14.0.2
- Selenium version: 3.141.59

#### Project link: [github](https://github.com/Dmilut/selenium-webdriver)

#### Dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Try to specify the location of your firefox binary like this: `options.setBinary(Paths.get("/path/to/your/binary"));`. You might have several browsers installed and since geckodriver takes the first from the list it might be not compatible with the driver.

Comment: Hi @Alexey, thank you for your helping. I tied your solution, but unfortunately I still have this error. I have only one firefox browser installed:
`[dmitrii@arch ~]$ which firefox
/usr/bin/firefox`